# Main/Test Error: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

I'm confused. Can someone help me with this error on this line: ->v

```
Undergraduate undergraduate1 = new Undergraduate();
```

ERROR: 
constructor Undergraduate in class Undergraduate cannot be applied to given types;
*required:
java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int,double,int,java.lang.String*
**found: no arguments
reason:actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Main / Test Class:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Main
 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      Undergraduate undergraduate1 = new Undergraduate();

      int satScore;
      String classYear;

      satScore = Integer.parseInt(
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter sat scores") );
      String classyear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter class year");


      undergraduate1.setSatScore(satScore);
      undergraduate1.setClassYear(classYear);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         "Sat Score: " + undergraduate1.getSatScore()
         + "\nClass Year: " + undergraduate1.getClassYear() );

    }
 }
```

Undergraduate Class (SubClass):

```
public class Undergraduate extends Student
{
    private int satScore;
    private String classYear;

    // ArrayList that maintains a list of valid department names for faculty members
    private ArrayList<String> classYearList;

    /** The constructor sets initial value for the class year field.
     *  Explicit call to superclass Employee sets initial values for
     *  fields firstName, lastName and studentID and gradePointAvg.
     *  Instantiates and adds classYear to the 'classYearList' ArrayList.
     *
     *  @param firstName Undergraduate Student's first name from indirect superclass Student
     *  @param lastName Undergraduate Student's last name from indirect superclass Student
     *  @param gradePointAvg the GPA of the Undegraduate Student
     *  @param classYear the year of the Undergraduate Student
     */
    public Undergraduate(String firstName, String lastName, int studentID, double gradePointAvg, int satScore, String classYear)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName, studentID, gradePointAvg);

        classYearList = new ArrayList<String>();

        classYearList.add("FRESHMAN");
        classYearList.add("SOPHMORE");
        classYearList.add("JUNIOR");
        classYearList.add("SENIOR");

        setClassYear(classYear);
        setSatScore(satScore);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sat score of the Undergraduates.
     * This sat Score must be between 600 and 2400 , or zero  (0) meaning sat score not set.
     *
     * @param satScore sat Score range of Undergraduates
     */

    public void setSatScore(int satScore)
    {
        if ( (satScore >= 600 && satScore <= 2400) || satScore ==0)
        {
           this.satScore = satScore;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the degree earned as either Feshman, Sophmore, Junior, Senior.
     *
     * @param class year of the Undergraduates
     */
     public void setClassYear(String classYear)
    {
        if (classYear.indexOf(classYear) >=0)
        {
          this.classYear = classYear;
        }
    }

    /**Returns current value of the satScore field.
    *
    *@return satsores of students as data type int.
    */
    public int getSatScore()
    {
        return satScore;
    }

    /**Returns current value of the classYear field.
    *
    * @return class year of of students as data type String.
    */
    public String getClassYear()
    {
        return classYear;
    }

    /** Returns fields satScore and classYear fields 
     *  including labels.
     *
     * @return Formatted sat score and class year fields as type String
     */

    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + "\nSat Score: " + getSatScore()
                                + "\nClass Year: " + getClassYear();
    }
}
```

Please help me fix this issue with a clear explanation. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have explicit default constructor if you have another constructor as:

```
public class Undergraduate extends Student
{
   public Undergraduate() {}
   //

}
```

So you can create instance of Undergraduate as:

```
public class Main
 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      Undergraduate undergraduate1 = new Undergraduate(); // it needs default constructor
      // . . .
    }
}
```